# JS string to array of number

Tags: javascript

So i have this string

```
first €999, second €111
```

Im trying to make an array that looks like this (numbers after every €)

```
999,111
```

Edit:

Yes i have tried to split it but wont work. i tried to look it up on google and found something with indexof but that only returned the number of the last €.

```
       rowData[2].split('€').map(Number);
       parseInt(rowData[2].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10);
       split(rowData[2].indexOf("€") + 1);
```

The numbers are variable.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Now what have **you** done to try and solve this? What did you get stuck on? No one is going to just write the code for you.

Comment: Are the numbers after the characater always 3 digits, or is it variable?

Comment: Will they always be integers or will they be floating point numbers like 999.99?

Comment: `str.match(/\d+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var input ="first €999, second €111";
var output=[];
var arr = input.split(",");
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    output.push(parseInt(arr[i]));
}
var output_string = output.stingify();
console.log(output); //Output Array
console.log(output_string); //Output String
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers will always be of 3 digits in length, you can do this.  If not, you need to specify a bit more.

```
var string = "€999, second €111";
var temp = [];
var digitArray = [];
temp = string.split(",");
for(var i=0;i<temp.length,i++){
   digitArray.push(temp[i].substring(temp[i].indexOf("€"),3));
}

//digitArray now contains [999,111];
```

**Edit, based on your requirement of variable digit lengths**

```
var string = "€999, second €111, third €32342";
var temp = [];
var digitArray = [];
temp = string.split(",");
for(var i=0;i<temp.length,i++){
   digitArray.push(temp[i].replace(/^\D+/g, ''));  //Replace all non digits with empty.
}

//digitArray now contains [999,111,32342]
```